# Diagram of stress - strain in TIKZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, technical-drawing

I'm having trouble starting the strain-strain diagram, could someone help me start this process?[image]

Comment: Hi Heron, do you have a MWE you can share?

Answer (score 2):

Since no-one else has helped, here is an effort in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html), which you might like to learn.  Follow the link for manuals and tutorials.  This is wrapped up in `luamplib` so you need to compile it with `lualatex`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    path xx, yy, ff;
    xx = origin -- 377 right;
    yy = origin -- 233 up;
    ff = origin .. (72, 144){1,2} .. (84, 144) .. (96, 144){1,1} .. (200, 220){right} .. (340, 160){2,-1.3};

    for t=2, 4, 4.9:
        draw point t of ff -- (xpart point t of ff, ypart point 1 of yy + 20) dashed evenly scaled 1/2;
    endfor
    label.top("Strain hardening", (1/2 (xpart point 2 of ff + xpart point 4 of ff), ypart point 1 of yy));
    label.top("Necking", (1/2 (xpart point 4 of ff + xpart point 4.9 of ff), ypart point 1 of yy));

    path rr; 
    rr = point 0.4 of ff -- (xpart point 0.8 of ff, ypart point 0.4 of ff) -- point 0.8 of ff;
    draw rr; label.bot("Run", point 1/2 of rr); label.rt("Rise", point 3/2 of rr);

    vardef pin_label@#(expr p, a, b)= 
        draw a -- b cutbefore fullcircle scaled 8 shifted a withpen pencircle scaled 1/4 withcolor 1/2 white;
        label@#(p, b);
    enddef;

    pin_label.lrt("Yield strength", point 1.2 of ff, point 2 of ff + (8, -18));
    pin_label.bot("Ultimate strength", point 4 of ff, point 4 of ff - (4, 24));
    pin_label.lrt("Fracture", point 5 of ff, point 5 of ff + (12, -18));

    color french_blue; french_blue = 1/256(50, 122, 177);
    draw ff withpen pencircle scaled 1 withcolor french_blue;

    drawarrow xx; label.rt("Strain, $\epsilon$", point 1 of xx);
    drawarrow yy; label.top("Stress, $\sigma$", point 1 of yy);

    label("$\displaystyle\hbox{Young's modulus} = \hbox{Slope} = {\hbox{Rise}\over\hbox{Run}}$", point 1/2 of xx shifted 36 up);

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

I have made extensive use here of the `point t of P` syntax, which returns an `(x,y)` pair that are at point `t` along a path `P`.